# How to use a python logger in an external script?

Tags: python, logging

My python project is structured as so...

```
root/
    Scripts/
        /script1.py
    Functions/
        /useful_functions.py
```

My code starts in script1.py and that is also where I create my logger.
Within script1.py I call functions located in useful_functions.py.
Currently I'm passing my logger but as my project grows I'm passing my logger into a lot of functions and I'm wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to achieve this.

```py
from Functions.useful_functions import *

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

get_users_address(user='John', logger)
```

```py
def get_users_address(user, logger):
    if user == 'John':
        logger.debug('Getting Johns address')
        return '123 Road'
    else:
        return '456 Street'
```